# Is it possible to override virtual functions with external friend lambda functions?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, c++14

I am writing some game code. I have an abstract game object class, and I want to make many various instances of the class. I want to write them quickly, without writing subclasses for each of them, so I tried to override the virtual functions with external friend lambda functions. Here is some simplified code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class B {
public:
    virtual ~B() = default;
    virtual void g() = 0;
protected:
    int x_ = 42;
};

template<typename F>
class C : public B {
public:
    C(F f) : f_(f) {}
    void g() override { f_(*this); }
private:
    F f_;
    friend decltype(f_);
};

template<typename F>
std::unique_ptr<B> make_c(F f) {
    return std::make_unique<C<F>>(f);
}

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<B> c = make_c([](auto& self) {
        std::cout << self.x_ << "\n";
    });
    c->g();

    return 0;
}
```

I tried this code with Clang and GCC. Clang compiles it, but GCC dies with an internal compiler error:

- Clang: https://wandbox.org/permlink/Kw82BdsKYEg0i2ln
- GCC: https://wandbox.org/permlink/F344XvvzO2JJH8Fa

I tried changing the argument type of the lambda from `auto&` to `B&`. Then, neither GCC and Clang will compile it, saying "`int B::x_` is protected within this context".

Is my code valid? If not, do some alternative methods exist?

Why does Clang compile it while GCC fails?

Comment: FWIW MSVS also compiles.

Comment: friend just affects the class' own members, not inherited ones...

Comment: You can easily make `C` a `struct` with all public - an instantiation of `C<Anything>` gives `Anything` full access to `C`, which makes access control useless

Comment: Your lambda is trying to access protected members of `B`, which is only possible if it is a member of `B` or of a derived class (which it is not - hence the refusal to compile).   Being a friend of `C<F>` does not make it a friend of `B`.

Comment: Okay, I understood my approach was wrong. Thank you. @Slava I [tried now](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1Fpy9GBYlBeRyEiG). It worked both on GCC and Clang. Writing `using`s are annoying a little, but I will go with it for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not really see how to get around the limitation of friend just with C++ means. However consider the following:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    class : public B
    {
    public:
        virtual void g() override { std::cout << x_ << "\n"; }
    } c;
    c.g();

    return 0;
}
```

Anonymous class with single instance. Sure, not yet what you are after, but it can be the base for some macro magic...

```
#define MAKE_GENERIC_B(INSTANCE_NAME, IMPLEMENTATION) \
class : public B                                      \
{                                                     \
public:                                               \
    virtual void g() IMPLEMENTATION                   \
} INSTANCE_NAME

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    MAKE_GENERIC_B(c,                             \
            {                                     \
                    char a[12] = { };             \
                    char d[10] = { };             \
                    memcpy(a, d, sizeof(d));      \
                    std::cout << x_ << std::endl; \
            }                                     \
    );
    c.g();
    return 0;
}
```

Suppose that comes quite close to what you are after. Multi-line implementations as illustrated come with quite ugly line endings, though, but if you have many short implementations that fit into a single line, it might be interesting...

***Edit:*** Using `std::unique_ptr`:

```
#define CONCAT_(X, Y) X ## Y
#define CONCAT(X, Y) CONCAT_(X, Y)
#define MAKE_C() CONCAT(C, __LINE__)

#define MAKE_GENERIC_B(INSTANCE_NAME, IMPLEMENTATION) \
class MAKE_C() : public B                             \
{                                                     \
public:                                               \
    virtual void g() IMPLEMENTATION                   \
}; auto INSTANCE_NAME = std::make_unique<MAKE_C()>()

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    MAKE_GENERIC_B(c,                             \
            {                                     \
                    char a[12] = { };             \
                    char d[10] = { };             \
                    memcpy(a, d, sizeof(d));      \
                    std::cout << x_ << std::endl; \
            }                                     \
    );
    c->g();

    MAKE_GENERIC_B(d, { std::cout << x_ * 2 << std::endl; });
    d->g();

    return 0;
}
```

As we cannot define classes in template arguments, we need to define it in advance. To get individual names, I use the `__LINE__` macro, an alternative could be providing a class name as macro parameter.

Additionally, with the now named classes, you could provide a constructor, too, and even extend the macro to feed in parameters to it, if need be...

Comment: Interesting (and I did not know about anonymous class). A problem is that instances are created on the stack. This makes memory/lifetime management harder (and that's why I used `unique_ptr`). Unfortunately I could not find a workaround.

Comment: @vabuff Your unique_ptr goes out of scope just the same way as my class on stack does - so life time is the same... Memory - well, if the classes are small, might even be preferable keeping them on the stack, otherwise, one could adjust the macro to use std::unique_ptr again.